# Update fields for a file in Sharepoint document library with Graph SDK C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm using the C# SDK for the Graph API in my C# application to work with Sharepoint.
This works fine for filling up a List with data with custom fields and uploading files in a document library also works fine. However, updating custom fields for a file in a document library doesn't seem to work.

I'm using .NET 6 and the Microsoft.Graph NuGet package (5.27.0)

I use the following request to upload the file:

```
 var newFile = graphClient
        .Drives[await GetDriveId(docLibraryName, link)]
        .Root
        .ItemWithPath(fileName)
        .Content
        .PutAsync(fileStream);
```

GetDriveId() will use the Site Id to fetch the drive id of the document library

I use the id from that upload to get the id of the ListItem:

```
var listItem = await graphClient
    .Drives[await GetDriveId(docLibraryName, link)]
    .Items[newFile.Id]
    .ListItem
    .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Id" };
    });
```

After that I use the id to update the fields of the ListItem:

```
var itemToAdd = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.ListItem
{
    Fields = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.FieldValueSet
    {
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { SpoDocument.Owner, document.Owner },
            { SpoDocument.Datum, document.Datum },
            { SpoDocument.Ref1, document.Ref1 },
            { SpoDocument.Ref2, document.Ref2 },
            { SpoDocument.Ref3, document.Ref3 },
            { SpoDocument.Ref4, document.Ref4 },
            { SpoDocument.MailTo, document.MailTo },
            { SpoDocument.MailBcc, document.MailBCC },
            { SpoDocument.MailCc, document.MailCC },
            { SpoDocument.BodyMail, document.BodyMail },
            { SpoDocument.ContactPersonen, document.Contactpersonen },
            { SpoDocument.Activiteit, document.Activiteit },
            { SpoDocument.VerkoopCategorie, document.VerkoopCategorie },
            { SpoDocument.InkoopCategorie, document.InkoopCategorie },
        }
    }
};

 await graphClient
 .Drives[await GetDriveId(docLibraryName, link)]
 .List
 .Items[listItem.Id]
 .PatchAsync(itemToAdd)
```

This however returns an exception with "General exception while processing". The SpoDocumentClass just contains constant strings with the available columns in the document library,
[here you can see some columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNsOP.png)

If afterwards I try to fetch those custom fields using the following function they don't appear in the list of fields which makes me think they are not available somehow? [As can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rRzy.png)

```
var test = await graphClient
    .Drives[await GetDriveId(docLibraryName, link)]
    .Items[fileId]
    .ListItem
    .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "Fields" };
    });
```

If however I fetch the list of columns of the document library, they do appear in there [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLQGu.png)

```
var test2 = await graphClient
    .Drives[await GetDriveId(docLibraryName, link)]
    .List.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "Columns" };
    });
```

I would like to be able to update the fields of my document in the document library using the Graph SDK

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code to Update fields

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "YourClientId";
        string clientSecret = "YourClientSecret";
        string tenantId = "YourTenantId";
        string siteId = "YourSiteId";
        string documentLibraryId = "YourDocumentLibraryId";
        string fileId = "YourFileId";

        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
            .Build();

        var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication, "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

        var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        // Define the properties you want to update
        var updatedProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "Title", "New Title" },
            { "Description", "New Description" },
            // Add other properties as needed
        };

        // Update file properties
        var updatedDriveItem = await graphServiceClient
            .Sites[siteId]
            .Drives[documentLibraryId]
            .Items[fileId]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(new DriveItem
            {
                AdditionalData = updatedProperties,
            });

        Console.WriteLine($"Updated file properties. New title: {updatedDriveItem.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but I eventually found the next day that one of the properties I was sending was of the wrong type for its column. It's a shame the error is so generic that you need to go on a whole quest to find what's wrong